# Restringir el acceso al contenido del modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, modal

Tengo un problema con los modals. Tengo un botón que al pulsarlo me permite acceder al modal. La cuestión es que quiero comprobar si se goza de unas condiciones o no que permitan al usuario acceder al modal.
¿Cómo debería modificar el botón para que me permita acceder al modal si y solo si se cumple una condición?
Adjunto el código del botón

`<button class="btn btn-type1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editPhoto" onclick="checkAutorizationEdit()" id="edit-button">Editar foto</button>`

data-target="#editPhoto" me permite asociarlo al modal correspondiente.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Usando solamente los atributos `data` que nos ofrece **Bootstrap** para el uso de sus modales, no podrías directamente. Pero podrías hacerlo a través de la función `onclick` con la que pareces estar validando la autorización. En caso de cumplirla abres la modal desde **JS** y en caso de que no haces lo que creas mejor para informar al usuario.

Para abrir y cerrar modales Bootstrap tenemos la función `modal()` a la que podemos pasarle o *show* o *hide* como parámetro.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.btn').click(function () {
    let condicion = $(this).attr('id');

    if(condicion == 'si') {
     $('.modal').modal('show');
    }
    else {
      console.log('No tienes permisos');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="si" class="btn">Llamar modal CON permisos</button>
<button id="no" class="btn">Llamar modal SIN permisos</button>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Mi modal</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Wasssssaaaaaaaaaa</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap te brinda un [api](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#usage) para manipular los modals desde js.

Puedes añadir la función para validar las condiciones y borrar los atributos de bootstrap para el toggle de los modals.

Y dentro de tu función mostrar el modal.

```
<button class="btn btn-type1" onclick="checkAutorizationEdit()" id="edit-button">Editar foto</button>
```

```
function checkAutorizationEdit(){
   // tu validacion
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```